# "To think" idiom

Tags: meaning, idioms

I have this Magic: The Gathering card flavor text: “To think some believe it peaceful to die in one's sleep.”

[image]

What exactly that “to think” means?

Comment: You can see translations here: http://magiccards.info/jou/en/76.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this context, “to think” is like “I can't believe...” or “It is strange...”. 
The phrase on the card means “I can't believe that some people think it is peaceful to die in his/her sleep”. 
Examples:

- To think some people don't like candy.
- To think he lives near the beach but can't swim.

It is kind of an antiquated phrase and isn't used all that often.

Comment: Does it work work with any other verbs? Or is it just “to think” idiom?

Comment: Side note: It seems to me that there should be a comma or even a semi-colon in there. "To think; some believe... "

Comment: As far as I know, there is only "to think" as an idiom, but someone please correct me if you know of any others.

Comment: I've seen at as "just think", or sometimes "_and_ to think," as in [this famous example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_to_Think_That_I_Saw_It_on_Mulberry_Street). I suppose it could be punctuated as, _"Just think! Some believe it peaceful..."_

Comment: Shouldn't it be "to think some believe it's peaceful..."?

Answer (score 0):

"**to think**" here refers to the meaning of both **just think about it** or rather **take thought** and **can you imagine**. I would suggest to separate it from the rest of the sentence by a comma.

- To think, some people don't want to be rich.